# How can i solve 'non-existent field' error (in MATLAB) during calculating color channels entropy of 800+ images and showing percentage?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, entropy

I want to scan a folder of 800 images to calculate their RGB channel-wise entropy (entropy for each color channel). Then to calculate what percent of my images has higher red channel entropy than the blue channel. I have added the whole code below, when I run this, it shows an error:

```
Reference to non-existent field 'folder'.

Error in Untitled (line 3)
   im = fullfile(files(k).folder, files(k).name);
```

I am currently using MATLAB 2015b version.

```
files = dir('F:\images\*.png');  % Or whatever filter will pick your images
for k = 1 : length(files)
   im = fullfile(files(k).folder, files(k).name);
   im = imread(im);
   I= im;
Red = I(:,:,1);
Green = I(:,:,2);
Blue = I(:,:,3);

%I = I(:); % Vectorization of RGB values
p = imhist(Red); % Histogram
p(p == 0) = [ ];% remove zero entries in p
p = p ./ numel(I); % normalize p so that sum(p) is one.
Er = round(-sum(p.*log2(p)),3);

p = imhist(Blue); % Histogram
p(p == 0) = [ ];% remove zero entries in p
p = p ./ numel(I); % normalize p so that sum(p) is one.
Eb = round(-sum(p.*log2(p)),3);

end

percentage = sum(Er > Eb) / numel(Er) * 100; % Percentage of images with red entropy higher than blue entropy

disp(['Percentage of images with red entropy higher than blue entropy: ' num2str(percentage)])
```

I have also uploaded the [folder](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1L0CEtbZvlXKN-V4QU7Attx1eRrQ_lalR?usp=sharing) which contains now only 5 PNG images instead of 800+ images.

Comment: Interesting. What happens if you display `files` after the first line? (BTW, everything except line 1 and line 3 is irrelevant to the question. The first part of [mre] is "minimal".)

Comment: sorry i couldn't understand

Comment: Which part did you not understand?

Comment: the "display files" part.

Comment: After running the first line in the command window, type `files`. MATLAB will show you the size of the struct array `files` and the fields inside. Examine that output to confirm that the size is non-zero and that the field `folder` exists.